# Subclasses of GameInfo and Input in UDK

Tags: udk

We have two main subclasses of GameInfo for the two game types we have. I'm wondering if it's possible to get one of these to read a different .ini file because we'd like to move a few of the controls to different buttons for that mode.

It looks to me like it's just going to read Input.ini for this, regardless of the game type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a subclass of PlayerInput with its own section with keybinds in the Input.ini.

If the controls are different based solely on the map/GameInfo, you can make a subclass of your PlayerController, set its `InputClass` to your new PlayerInput subclass in defaultproperties, then in your GameInfo you can set `PlayerControllerClass` to your new PlayerController type. So that GameInfo will spawn that PlayerController with that PlayerInput type.

If instead you want to swap it at runtime, you can skip creating the PlayerController subclass. You'll have to find and remove the old PlayerInput from you PlayerController's `Interactions` array, set your `PlayerInput` to `none`, change your `InputClass`. After that, you can call InitInputSystem() and it'll reinitialize your input with the new class.